# Grid layout and expanding controls (TextBox)

Tags: wpf

I seem to not understand the layout behavior in my application. In the following sketch I have a TextBox that expands as text is being entered. How can I prevent that from happening and have the Height stay constant and get a Scrollbar instead? The size of the right TextBox should the size the left three TextBoxes take.

Initial state:

[image]

After adding several values:

[image]

Here's the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="LightBlue">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="One" Margin="5" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Two" Margin="5" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Three" Margin="5" />
         <TextBox
            Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5"
            AcceptsReturn="True"
            Text="Hello World!"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            />
    </Grid>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="Blue" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Just explicitly set the Width or the MaxWidth property of the Textbox and it should stop expending automatically.

Comment: `<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />` tells that the space will be allocated according to size of child controls

Comment: If you don't want the `TextBox` to grow indefinitely, you need to specify its maximum allowed height somewhere. You could for example do this by setting its `MaxHeight` property. Did you try this?

Comment: Thanks mm8. It is what I do right now. I thought there is a way to avoid using explicit size numbers that always need to be adjusted if something changes.

Comment: @JohannesSchacht: How is the layout system suppose to know how much you want the control to grow unless you specify this somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

## Simple Answer

Assuming that the font size and margins of the `TextBox`es are going to remain constant, and that the `TextBox`es on the left are single-line only, you can just set a fixed height for the top `RowDefinition`:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="84" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

---

## Complicated Answer

If the left `TextBox`es are multiline, or if the font size or margins can change, then you'll have to get a bit more complicated. I don't think there's an existing `Panel` that can handle that, you'd have to manually set the `Height` of the right `TextBox` to match the sum of the `ActualHeight + Margin.Top + Margin.Bottom` for all of the left `TextBox`es. This would need to be done whenever `SizeChanged` was raised on any of the left `TextBox`es.